# C# Creating a SSH-tunnel to connect to remote MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, ssh, tcpclient, tunnel

So I have been trying to connect to a remote server using a SSH-tunnel to reach the MySQL-database on the other side. It would seem like the SSH-part is finally doing my bidding, but trying to connect to MySQL throws "Reading from the stream has failed. ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException"

Entire message:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Reading from the stream has failed. ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Failed to read past end of stream.
   vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   vid Wrapper_Steleco.Databas.Database.<constructDatabase>d__11.MoveNext()
```

SSH.cp:

```
public async Task connectSSH()
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 3307);
                Console.WriteLine("Port is open!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error pinging host: 'localhost:3307'");
            }
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("About to execute Plink.");
                    ProcessStartInfo plink = new ProcessStartInfo()
                    {
                        FileName = @".\plink.exe",
                        Arguments = " -ssh -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 user@host -pw password -v",
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardInput = true,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        CreateNoWindow = false
                    };
                    Process process = Process.Start(plink);
                    Console.WriteLine("Executed plink...");

                    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("logout");
                    process.Kill();
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

And last, MySQL:

```
 public async void constructDatabase() // Konstruktor
        {
            SSH ssh = new SSH();
            try
            {
                var task = Task.Run(() => ssh.connectSSH());
                Console.WriteLine("Task-status: " + task.Status);
                try
                {
                    task.Wait();
                    using (task)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Task-status: " + task.Status);
                            Console.WriteLine("Database-connection continues.");
                            host = "127.0.0.1";
                            port = "3307";
                            dbName = "database";
                            uid = "user";
                            password = "password";
                            conString = "Server=" + host + "; Port=" + port + "; Database=" + dbName + "; Uid=" + uid + "; Pwd=" + password + "";
                            Console.WriteLine(conString);
                            conn = new MySqlConnection(conString);
                            Console.WriteLine("MySQL-state: " + conn.State.ToString());
                            conn.Open();
                            Console.WriteLine("MySQL-state: " + conn.State.ToString());
                        }
                        catch (MySqlException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                        }
                        catch (EndOfStreamException ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Stream exception caught: " + ex.Message.ToString());


                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (conn != null)
                            {
                                conn.Close();
                                conn.Dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                eventLog = new EventLog();
                eventLog.getError(EventLog.Errors.DatabaseConnectionError, 0, ex.ToString());
                connectionError = true;
            }

        }
```

I am quite new to C#, haven't used it in years and it is the first time I am attempting to set up such remote connection through a SSH-tunnel. I have pondered over if I am using the wrong type of methods or if I am just using the right methods wrong. Evidently there is something I am not doing correctly and I have been stuck on this for three days, going through page after page on both Google and StackOverflow without finding the answer which would solve this particular issue.

After some research and getting the plink-window to show; It seems like it is refusing the connection, for reasons unknown.

```
Local port 3307 forwarding to 127.0.0.1:3306
Opening connection to 127.0.0.1:3306 for forwarding from 127.0.0.1:52566
Forward connection refused by server: Connection failed [Connection refused]
```

Comment: Today, I got the same problem with MySql error is 1042 (**Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.**). I can connect by **A5 SQL** with setting in **SSH Tunnel** and **MySql** connection. But cannot do in C#... :(((((

Comment: Same problem! Did you find a solution?

Comment: @IgorIlyichyov, I did, but I do not remember it anymore.I think I opted "with()" or "using()" to keep the connection open to the tunnel while running the sql-code.